# PHP - parse_ini_(string|file) - Why do false and no values get truncated to empty strings?

Tags: php

So I'm working on cleaning up some older code and came across a snippet where we are doing parse_ini_string (for >=5.3) and parse_ini_file (for all others) and noticed that ini settings with values of false where being truncated to empty strings, but values of true were being changed from true to 1.

According to the [php docs](https://www.php.net/parse_ini_string) (under the notes section): 'Values null, no and false results in "", yes and true results in "1"'. This seems counter-intuitive. We want to allow support users the ability to enter true or false via frontend guis, vs having them enter 0 and 1 (as they don't speak binary). In order to do so, I had to add some hacktacular code to check for presence of a key, and if present but empty, assume the value was false before php parsed it.

Why would the php devs not ensure a consistent return of true or false with a return value of 1 or 0, vs what they are doing now, which is truncating the false to an empty string?

Comment: an empty string reacts in the same way like `"0"` if you do loose comparsion with `true` or `false`. http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Comment: See [#38409](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=38409). That it doesn't preserve types is because `zend_parse_ini_file` is also used for PHPs .ini file. And configuration values are interpreted according to its weak type system, there was never any need to discern between false and empty values.

Comment: @redreggae: Ya, I try to stay away from empty checks solely for that reason. As software guys we try to write algorithms which return a value (of the same datatype) no matter what (unless exception is thrown). This contract between the calling code and the algorithm ensures we don't end up with clumsy api calls, like what I had to endure. IMO, it should return 0 from a false setting and let the calling code deal with it.

Comment: @mario: Nice find. Although based on the response to redreggae, I think the contract between calling code and algorithm establishes that need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And what about own constants?

```
define('yep', '1');
define('nope', '0');

$iniString = "
foo = yep
bar = nope
";

var_dump(parse_ini_string($iniString));
```

**EDIT:**

According to goba@php.net it's a feature:

> This feature(!) is there so you can convert from booleans to strings, then back to booleans or to integers and then to booleans, and you get the same boolean you started from...

```
boolean -> string -> boolean
TRUE        "1"       TRUE
FALSE       ""        FALSE

boolean -> string -> integer -> boolean
TRUE        "1"        1         TRUE
FALSE       ""         0         FALSE
```

More info: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=19575

Comment: Wont' work for my sitch. The ini settings are set via a frontend gui by support users, which then get saved into database. Then read and parsed without any indication of what values might be in the settings (of which there are hundreds).

Comment: what I don't understand: if you have a frontend gui, why can't you just rewrite a true|false to 1|0 before the value is saved into the ini file?

Comment: We considered that too, but then we would have to undo the 1|0 back to true|false to be human readable for the support users, when they viewed it via gui. Anything is possible, but doesn't answer the question why the php function for parsing inis returns inconsistent output from consistent input.

Comment: I cannot really confirm it but goba@php.net says it's a feature: `This feature(!) is there so you can convert from booleans to strings, then back to booleans or to integers and then to booleans, and you get the same boolean you started from...` https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=19575

Comment: I added it to the answer..but I can't find an example where `"0"` would have a different output then `""`..

Comment: Ya it cycles back to the original problem, casting a boolean false as a string returns empty string, whereas casting boolean true as a string returns "1". Chalk it up to "loosely typed language".